# GRASS GIS, r.li modules: How to fix "ERROR: Illegal areas disposition"?

Tags: grass-gis, error, grass-7.8

While trying to run commands in examples of GRASS GIS `r.li` [module](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass-stable/manuals/r.li.patchdensity.html), I get the error.

This is the output I get from commands in the examples
`grass_cmd_output`(Language:Japanese)

```
(Fri Sep  4 13:12:18 2020)                                                      
g.gui.rlisetup                                                                  
(Fri Sep  4 13:12:21 2020) コマンド終了 (2 秒)                                         
(Fri Sep  4 13:12:24 2020)                                                      
g.region raster=geology_30m -p                                                  
projection: 99 (Lambert Conformal Conic)
zone:       0
datum:      nad83
ellipsoid:  a=6378137 es=0.006694380022900787
north:      228500
south:      215000
west:       630000
east:       645000
nsres:      30
ewres:      30
rows:       450
cols:       500
cells:      225000
(Fri Sep  4 13:12:24 2020) コマンド終了 (0 秒)                                         
(Fri Sep  4 13:12:27 2020)                                                      
r.li.patchdensity input=geology_30m conf=my_conf out=patchdens                  
ERROR: Illegal areas disposition
(Fri Sep  4 13:12:28 2020) コマンド終了 (0 秒)
```

Following [this article](https://trac.osgeo.org/grass/ticket/2327), there was the similar(=same?) problem only on Windows OS. I'm using Windows 10 64bit and GRASS 7.8.3 (Language:Japanese).

Could you suggest any solutions to fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

I tried it myself but no problem occurred:

```
GRASS nc_spm_08_grass7/user1:~ > g.gui.rlisetup
GRASS nc_spm_08_grass7/user1:~ > g.region raster=geology_30m -p      
projection: 99 (Lambert Conformal Conic)
zone:       0
datum:      nad83
ellipsoid:  a=6378137 es=0.006694380022900787
north:      228500
south:      215000
west:       630000
east:       645000
nsres:      30
ewres:      30
rows:       450
cols:       500
cells:      225000
GRASS nc_spm_08_grass7/user1:~ > r.li.patchdensity input=geology_30m conf=test out=patchdens
r.li.patchdensity complete. Result written to text file
</home/mneteler/.grass7/r.li/output/patchdens>
GRASS nc_spm_08_grass7/user1:~ > cat /home/mneteler/.grass7/r.li/output/patchdens
RESULT 1|0.0641975308641975
```

This looks ok. My configuration looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

GRASS GIS 7.8.7
To solve this issue, you need to edit your configuration file. You don't necessarily edit it per se.

Open the config file, then edit it by removing "MOVINGWINDOW" and confirm the edit. You can edit just anything on the file. Then run the algorithm. Obviously it's going to fail, then open the configuration file again, and restore it to its original state. Then run the algorithm again. This time it is going to work.

The solution is not really technical, I don't really understand why this manages to throw off the bug.